# Data (payload) omitted when invoking POST ajax request through Ripple proxy

Tags: jquery, cordova, ripple

I'm using **Cordova 2.3.0** and **Ripple 0.9.2** emulator Chrome extension.
When POSTing (`$.ajax`) my data (payload) is not sent with my url by the proxy.

Here is the final url including proxy:

https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=https%3A//mydomain.com/MobileFacade/login

This is a standard web service that responds correctly when invoked directly, i.e.

https://mydomain.com/MobileFacade/login

but breaks when called by proxy because the data is not passed on.

Any ideas?